# Setting max size of window in eclipse rcp

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

There is setMinimumSize option in Eclipse RCP but no setMaximumSize, is there any way to implement that type of function ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you could set a max. size to an app.
A workaround could be the following:
On your `ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` class, at `preWindowOpen()` method, you could set your maximum `configurer.setInitialSize()` and block the `maximize` function, hidding the button via `configurer.setShellStyle(SWT.MIN | SWT.CLOSE);`